# Creating transparent image with localGraphicsConfig not always working

Tags: 2d, java, windows, macos, transparency

I'm [trying](https://github.com/kozie/twodee/blob/master/src/nl/kozie/twodee/Display.java#L145) to use [`GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage%28int,%20int,%20int%29) to create transparent images.
This creates an empty image which I'm filling with a mosaic pattern later on in the code.

This seems to work like a charm on my iMac using the latest OSX.
When i switch (bootcamp) to Windows 7, the transparency doesn't work (just opaque images).
Is there something i'm missing?

I'm using Java 1.7.0_03 on Windows 7 (64)

I'm actually not quite sure if it's necessary to render the image using the `localGraphicsConfiguration` since the image/layer with the mosaic will never change. How can I solve this?